# Prolog for Quantum Logic Gate Simulator

Tags: prolog, quantum-computing

I don't know `Prolog`, but I'm wondering if it could be a good option for building a [Quantum Gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate) simulator?

My main question is what are the pros and cons of using `Prolog` for such a project? Also other suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You might be interested to look into CLP(R) which comes as a library for Prolog for this purpose. In any case, plan half-a-year+ for learning Prolog first.

Comment: @false thanks! Do you think I might be better to go for `C` for example, as I know it much better than `Prolog`, or there is any certain benefit using `Prolog` in this case?

Comment: Not sure how much math you will need. As a quick guess, apart from CLP(R), I would have said Mathematica. But both need to be learned first.

Comment: @false thanks again! I will take a look at both of them! :)

Answer (score -1):

I've written quantum logic simulators in C++ and Python. My first programming language was Prolog, but that was a long time ago. My recollections don't make me think it's the ideal choice: IIRC, return values were limited to True/False, and it seems to me one wants a little more flexibility in the values. Although it's true that one can use a True/False value to see, say, whether a surface code protected a circuit against errors, you might want to actually know the quantum amplitude for some of the values, and a more general programming language might help you.

The way I wrote my simulator, I used a lot of 2x2 and 4x4 matrix multiplies, and I found that the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) C++ library, which cache-optimizes a lot of smaller cases, was unbelievably fast. In these simulations, you often want to run **lots** of statistics, so that you can see how well the code protects when the input error rate is fairly small. The speed of Eigen made things really nice.

Comment: Thanks Rick for the input. It's seems to be a valid point that Prolog is not as flexible as, let say C++ or similar stuff. I'm actually looking for these answers to understand what are the pros and cons of using Prolog for such a thing. Thanks again for the answer! :)

Comment: It is absolutely false that in Prolog "return values were limited to True/False". Unification (which is what we can consider as "return values") can be done over arbitrarily complex data structures. This tutorial is a very good introduction to the language: http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/index.php